# How do I get a list of files with specific file extension using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The node [fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fs) package has the following methods to list a directory:

> **fs.readdir(path, [callback])** Asynchronous readdir(3). Reads the
>   contents of a directory. The callback gets two arguments (err, files)
>   where files is an array of the names of the files in the directory
>   excluding '.' and '..'.
>
> **fs.readdirSync(path)** Synchronous readdir(3). Returns an array of
>   filenames excluding '.' and '..

But how do I get a list of files matching a file specification, for example ***.txt**?

Comment: You'll get the list of all files the files in directory in your callback argument. You can filter that.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You could filter they array of files with an extension extractor function. The `path` module provides one such function, if you don't want to write your own string manipulation logic or regex.

```
const path = require('path');

const EXTENSION = '.txt';

const targetFiles = files.filter(file => {
    return path.extname(file).toLowerCase() === EXTENSION;
});
```

*EDIT*
As per @arboreal84's suggestion, you may want to consider cases such as `myfile.TXT`, not too uncommon. I just tested it myself and `path.extname` does not do lowercasing for you.

Comment: Almost correct. You need to lowercase the extension, as some files may use uppercased, e.g: `.TXT`

Comment: to someone doing copy/paste this answer is missing the actual reading of the directory which would be the case on the answer of Lazyexpert

Answer (score 32):

Basically, you do something like this:

```
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')

const dirpath = path.join(__dirname, '/path')

fs.readdir(dirpath, function(err, files) {
  const txtFiles = files.filter(el => path.extname(el) === '.txt')
  // do something with your files, by the way they are just filenames...
})
```

Comment: Don't parse the filename with a regex, use `path.extname`.

Comment: Does it make any difference? Or maybe you think it's faster than regexp?

Comment: Having to read a regular expression to understand your intention, and reading `path.extname`, which is documented. That saves time and money.

Comment: I agree, in some complex cases its all true. But this one, seriously: `/\.txt$/`, takes time to read and understand?

Comment: If there's an incident at 2 AM nobody wants to read your regex. Then imagine yourself writing a unit test for that, not worth it. Just use robust, well-tested libraries.

Comment: I wonder, how many time it took you to read and understand that regexp? How many ms? I repeat, in most cases - I totally agree. But the simpliest... what are we even talking about...?

Comment: 1) Code is written once, read many times. Make your code easier to read, not easy to write. 2) If the requirement is simple, why is the implementation more complex than it needs to? 3) This bad habit adds up to tech-debt spaghetti [very quickly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory)

Comment: its useless. This regexp complexity is equal 0. So far you approach has a dark side, newbie developers don't know what's the regexp, how to use it, how to read it, etc... If you don't show them even the simple regexps.

Comment: You can write `1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1`, that is 10. Everyone can add right? It has 0 complexity? But it is a **waste of time** for the reader. Just write `10`.
Having to do that sum in your head distracts the reader from understanding how `10` fits into the rest of the code.

Comment: Your example is not the same I'm talking about. This talk has no sense.

Comment: It is exactly the same. Using a built-in function that is well documented and has a self-explanatory name is more expressive than doing filter with a regex, however simple that may be, it distracts the reader. It doesn't matter how simple the code is, it's distracting and a waste of time and therefore a bad practice.

Comment: Current regexp consits of 90% descriptive text. What is waste of time... You don't take any time neither to read, nor to understand it. It is like a descriptive variable name. Noone is wasting time, you just read it and go on. The opposite is more complex regexp...

Comment: **You don't need a regex** for this, there's a built-in function for that, that is documented, tested and has a self-explanatory name. Unless you are willing to unit test your stuff then don't roll your own. Then, it's a bad security practice to manually parse paths and URLs yourself. Then, if you just wrote it, of course it looks self-evident. Think of someone else or yourself in 2 years reading it.

Comment: @arboreal84 revising this after several years, I tend to agree. Builtin functions do stuff better overall :)

Answer (score 8):

`fs` doesn't support filtering itself but if you don't want to filter youself then use [glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob)

```
var glob = require('glob');

// options is optional
glob("**/*.js", options, function (er, files) {
  // files is an array of filenames.
  // If the `nonull` option is set, and nothing
  // was found, then files is ["**/*.js"]
  // er is an error object or null.
})
```

Answer (score 7):

I used the following code and its working fine:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var dirPath = path.resolve(__dirname); // path to your directory goes here
var filesList;
fs.readdir(dirPath, function(err, files){
  filesList = files.filter(function(e){
    return path.extname(e).toLowerCase() === '.txt'
  });
  console.log(filesList);
});
```

Comment: Text file extension can also be uppercased (e.g: `.TXT`)

Comment: yes you are right. Thanks for pointing out the possible problem :)

Answer (score 1):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
    
// Path to the directory(folder) to look into
const dirPath = path.resolve(`${__dirname}../../../../../tests_output`);
        
// Read all files with .txt extension in the specified folder above
const filesList = fs.readdirSync(dirPath, (err, files) => files.filter((e) => path.extname(e).toLowerCase() === '.txt'));
        
// Read the content of the first file with .txt extension in the folder
const data = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(`${__dirname}../../../../../tests_output/${filesList[0]}`), 'utf8');
```