# How to zip only the html files in a folder having different extensions using nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have a folder which has got files with many extensions like html and txt. I need to zip only the html files in that folder.

I tried like -

```
const archiver = require("archiver");
const fs = require("fs");

function zipDirectory(source, out) {
    const archive = archiver("zip", { zlib: { level: 9 } });
    const stream = fs.createWriteStream(out);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      archive
        .directory(source, false)
        .on("error", err => reject(err))
        .pipe(stream);

      stream.on("close", () => resolve());
      archive.finalize();
    });
  }


  zipDirectory('./sample/*.html', 'sam.zip');
```

But didnt work. How can I zip only the files with extension HTML alone. Please help

Comment: Check the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44199883/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-files-with-specific-file-extension-using-node-js You can get an array of all the files with a extension and then proccess them as you need.

Comment: not sure. Zip uploads a folder