# Read files of dictionary to export them in index file

Tags: javascript

There is a simple `index.ts` file to export multiple gql strings, which are stored in a file.
Every string has its own file - there are a few hundreds of them and all files are in the same folder.

So right now I'm doing this manually, which is quit bad.

```
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'

export const selectUser = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'selectUser.gql'), 'utf8');
export const updateUser = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'updateUser.gql'), 'utf8');
// many many more... file name is always export name
```

Isn't it possible to export all *.gql files in this directory by its name to make this file more dynamic?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a list of files with specific file extension using node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44199883/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-files-with-specific-file-extension-using-node-js)

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 Thanks. I understand how to read the files, but how do I export them like shown in my post?

Comment: You could export an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not export dynamically created `const`s, because a `const` must be declared before the code actually executes.

You could declare one `const`, which can be dynamically changed when the code is executed.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const folderName = 'manytiny/';
const folderPath = path.join(__dirname, folderName)

const myTexts = {};

fs.readdir( folderPath, function( err, fileList ){
    fileList.forEach( function( fileName ){
        const content = fs.readFileSync( path.join( folderPath, fileName ) );
        const propName = fileName.split('.')[0];
        myTexts[ propName ] = content;
    });
    console.log('', myTexts);
})

export myTexts;
```