# filtered by name using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes

Is there any way i can filter files with given extension and then further filter them
for eg: I have `.txt` extension and i want to get all my `.txt` from an array

```
file= 
[ "animal_bio.txt",
  "xray.pdf",
  "fish_bio.txt",
  "mammal_doc.txt",
  "human_bio.txt",
  "machine.jpg"
]
```

filtered output contain all `.txt` extension and further it should contain all the files which have `_bio.txt` name in it.

so output look like

```
futherFile=
[ "human_bio.txt",
  "fish_bio.txt",
  "animal_bio.txt"
]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44199883/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-files-with-specific-file-extension-using-node-js

Comment: So you want all `txt` files and then group them by the suffix after `_` - is that right? Did you try anything at all? Show your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.protytype.endsWith` function to compare the strings with your extension

```js
const file = 
[ "animal_bio.txt",
  "xray.pdf",
  "fish_bio.txt",
  "mammal_doc.txt",
  "human_bio.txt",
  "machine.jpg"
]
result = file.filter((fileName) => fileName.endsWith("_bio.txt"));
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Array.filter` method and use the `String.endsWith` method to filter. An example -

```js
// List of files

file = ["animal_bio.txt",
  "xray.pdf",
  "fish_bio.txt",
  "mammal_doc.txt",
  "human_bio.txt",
  "machine.jpg"
]

// Filtering by extension

file.filter(x => x.endsWith(".txt"));
```

Hope it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this result using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

When matching for the `doc` or `bio`, You can even restrict more to get the string only if `_doc.txt` is at end of the string using Regular expression `/_bio.txt$/`

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "animal_bio.txt",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "xray.pdf",
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "animal_doc.txt",
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    name: "fish_doc.txt",
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    name: "flower_petals.jpg",
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    name: "plant_roots.jpg",
  },
  {
    id: "6",
    name: "human_image.jpg",
  },
  {
    id: "7",
    name: "human_bio.txt",
  },
  {
    id: "8",
    name: "mammal_doc.txt",
  },
];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, { name }) => {
    if (name.match(/\.txt$/)) {
      if (name.match(/_bio/)) {
        acc[0].push(name);
      } else {
        acc[1].push(name);
      }
    }
    return acc;
  },
  [[], []]
);

console.log(result);
```

Then you can get the element containing `doc` and `bio` using array destructuring as

```
const [bioArr, docArr] = result;
console.log(bioArr);
console.log(docArr);
```

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "animal_bio.txt",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "xray.pdf",
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "animal_doc.txt",
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    name: "fish_doc.txt",
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    name: "flower_petals.jpg",
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    name: "plant_roots.jpg",
  },
  {
    id: "6",
    name: "human_image.jpg",
  },
  {
    id: "7",
    name: "human_bio.txt",
  },
  {
    id: "8",
    name: "mammal_doc.txt",
  },
];

const result = arr.reduce(
  (acc, { name }) => {
    if (name.match(/\.txt$/)) {
      if (name.match(/_bio/)) {
        acc[0].push(name);
      } else {
        acc[1].push(name);
      }
    }
    return acc;
  },
  [[], []]
);

const [bioArr, docArr] = result;
console.log(bioArr);
console.log(docArr);
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough :(. Using `/\.txt/` to match an extension is a bug - I know because I made the same mistake once and it caused problems. Match `/\.txt$/` to only match `.txt` as an extension but not if it occurs somewhere else in the filename.

Answer (score 0):

you can use filter function from ES6 like:

```
const txtFile = file.filter((item) => (item.split('_'))[1] === 'bio.txt')
```