# filter object key and value using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, nodes

Is there any way i can filter files with given extension and then further filter them for eg:
I have `.txt` extension and i want to get all my `.txt` from an array

```js
 [ { id: '1'    , name: 'animal_bio.txt'    }
 , { id: '2'    , name: 'xray.pdf'          }
 , { id: '3'    , name: 'animal_doc.txt'    }
 , { id: '4'    , name: 'fish_doc.txt'      }
 , { id: '5'    , name: 'flower_petals.jpg' }
 , { id: '5'    , name: 'plant_roots.jpg'   }
 , { id: '6'    , name: 'human_image.jpg'   }
 , { id: '7'    , name: 'human_bio.txt'     }
 , { id: '8'    , name: 'mammal_doc.txt'    }
 ]
```

Output:

```
file=
["animal_doc.txt"
 "fish_doc.txt"
 "mammal_doc.txt"
]

restText=
["animal_bio.txt"
 "human_bio.txt"
]
```

Comment: You have [already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67684147/filtered-by-name-using-node-js) this question today and accepted the answer, what's the matter?